# javascript function returns tagname in a given url

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that can return number of tabname in a given URL. I have the following code so far, which doesn't work.

I would like to display number of paragraphs in cnn.com or any other website at innerHTML.

```
function myFunction() 
{
    var currentURL = document.URL;

    document.getElementById("links").innerHTML = currentURL;
    location.assign("www.cnn.com");
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

    location.assign(currentURL);
    document.getElementById("links").innerHTML = x.length;
}
```

Comment: Javascript has a same-origin policy, you can't get the content from cnn.com, or any other cross domain site? In your code, the second you change the location and go to CNN, all your javascript is lost, and you can't run javascript on another page like that either.

Comment: I've used PHP's `DOMDocument` to scrape before. Then you don't have to worry about the same-origin policy. Also, once you use `location.assign("www.cnn.com")` their JavaScript loads, not yours.

Comment: Why are you doing this with Javascript if you have the DOM in PHP?

Comment: `var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]; x.innerHTML.length`

Comment: `avril alejandro`, your comment makes no sense. That would be length of the String in the first paragraph.